# Objective-C : Calling a property of a class in another

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using Cocos2d and I can not access properties of an object from another one.
Here I just want to get the hitpoints of a ship form a scene. It fails and returns an error : **uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCSprite hitpoints]: unrecognized selector...**

As hitpoints is declared in the interface of the class Ship I can't figure out why.
The only thing I understand is that it's a inhéritance issue.

Let's show some code :

Ship.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface Ship : CCSprite {
    int hitpoints;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int hitpoints;

- (id)init;

@end
```

Then Ship.m

```
#import "Ship.h"

@implementation Ship

@synthesize hitpoints;

- (id)init
{
    hitpoints = 3;
    self = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"ship.png"];
    return self;
}
@end
```

In the Scene.m

```
#import "Ship.h"
@implementation Scene
{
    Ship *_player;
}

- (id)init
{
    _player = [[Ship alloc] init];

    [self addChild:_player];

    // ERROR HERE
    NSLog(@"%s = %d", "_player hp", [_player hitpoints]);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue is with your `init` method; you shouldn't be accessing properties until the object is initialised and you should be calling `[super initWith...]` instead of the class creation method.

I would suggest the following changes:

Ship.h:

```
@interface Ship : CCSprite

@property (nonatomic, assign) int hitpoints;

@end
```

Ship.m:

```
#import "Ship.h"

@implementation Ship

@synthesize hitpoints;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithImageNamed:@"ship.png"];
    if (self) {
        self.hitpoints = 3;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Always use `object.property` when referencing a property, even when `object == self`.

Comment: Unrecognized selector is not a setter but a getter. and I don't agree with that the object isn't created.

Comment: @KyokookHwang OK, fixed wording.  And you are right about the setter/getter.  The issue is in the `init` method though.

Comment: Thank you. I was sure it was something like that and your detailled answer explained me a lot of things !

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
- (id)init
```

Means "a method that returns any kind of object, which is called `init`".

This:

```
self = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"ship.png"];
```

Means "create an instance of `CCSprite`". You then return that instance.

So `_player` ends up being an instance of `CCSprite`. `CCSprite` does not implement `hitpoints` so the exception is raised.

What are you actually trying to achieve? A subclass of `CCSprite`? trojanfoe has covered how to write a proper `init` for that. Things I think you need to know:

- all classes look the same at runtime;
- declaring the type of class pointers helps humans and the compiler to check your code but doesn't change the code generated;
- some Objective-C patterns (probably most notably including class clusters) are built around `init` being able to return any kind of class — it's a useful feature, not a misfeature.